# SQL Update Statement using If When

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to update one column if it's null with the values of another column only if that column is not null as well.  If it is null, then update column 1 with column 3

Here is an example:

```
day_phone       sec_phone       alt_phone       cell_phone
555-555-1212    NULL            NULL            NULL
NULL            555-555-1234    NULL            NULL
NULL            NULL            555-555-4321    NULL
NULL            NULL            NULL            555-555-5678
NULL            555-123-4567    555-867-5309    NULL
```

So what I want to accomplish is to update all records so that way day_phone ends up with a result, preferably the first one it finds if there are records in multiple columns.  The end result should look like this:

```
day_phone       sec_phone       alt_phone       cell_phone
555-555-1212    NULL            NULL            NULL
555-555-1234    555-555-1234    NULL            NULL
555-555-4321    NULL            555-555-4321    NULL
555-555-5678    NULL            NULL            555-555-5678
555-123-4567    555-123-4567    555-867-5309    NULL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply use `COALESCE`

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     day_phone = COALESCE(day_phone, sec_phone, alt_phone, cell_phone)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0118d/1)

if you want to update only if `day_phone` is null, then you can add extra condition,

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     day_phone = COALESCE(sec_phone, alt_phone, cell_phone)
WHERE   day_phone IS NULL
```

this will make the update more faster since only the selected rows are being updated. Much more faster if you have an index on column `day_phone`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was pretty simple, I just have never used COALESCE before (SQL beginner).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be a series of update statements.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=column2
WHERE column1 IS NULL
AND column2 IS NOT NULL
```

repeat for column 3, 4, etc...  Run in order of preference.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp